# pptpsetup meet error: "EAP: unknown authentication type 26; Naking"

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, pptp

The OS is ubuntu 12.04-lts, when using pptpsetup to setup and initiate a VPN connection, it reports:

```
    $sudo pptpsetup --create vpn --server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --username xxx --password xxx --encrypt --start
    Connect: ppp0  /dev/pts/1
    EAP: unknown authentication type 26; Naking
    EAP: peer reports authentication failure
    Connection terminated.
```

Here is my /etc/ppp/options.pptp file:

```
    # Lock the port
    lock

    # Authentication
    # We don't need the tunnel server to authenticate itself
    noauth

    # We won't do PAP, EAP, CHAP, or MSCHAP, but we will accept MSCHAP-V2
    # (you may need to remove these refusals if the server is not using MPPE)
    refuse-pap
    refuse-eap
    refuse-chap
    refuse-mschap
    require-mppe-128

    # Compression
    # Turn off compression protocols we know won't be used
    nobsdcomp
    nodeflate
```

Answer (score 19):

I had same problem and tried a lot of combinations of authentication modes to connect to Windows host.

I solved leaving only `MSCHAPv2` selected in GUI interface.

Comment: Same happened to me in Ubuntu 18.04. This solution worked!

Comment: I also need to use this: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=24633 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1095546

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem (Mint 17) and found this question along with a bunch of tutorials, instructions, etc.

In my case, it turned out to be a missing entry in my peers file.  Looking at your commands, I'm guessing that would be /etc/ppp/peers/vpn and the entry is:
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp

Here is mine (I've changed the host, username, and tunnel name):

```
# written by pptpsetup
pty "pptp vpn.foo.com --nolaunchpppd"
lock
noauth
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
name USERNAME
remotename vpn
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam vpn
require-mppe-128
```

Without that file entry I would get the same auth failure error message you reported.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this same issue on Ubuntu 15.04. I had followed the instructions [given in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/295309), but the VPN connection wouldn't work and gave me the error `EAP: peer reports authentication failure` until I opened `/etc/ppp/options.pptp` and commented out the lines `refuse-chap` and `refuse-mschap`:

```
# We won't do PAP, EAP, CHAP, or MSCHAP, but we will accept MSCHAP-V2
# (you may need to remove these refusals if the server is not using MPPE)
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
# refuse-chap
# refuse-mschap
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by following [this guide](http://domwatson.codes/2015/04/connecting-to-windows-pptp-vpn-from-linux.html). Enable MPPT, which leaves only MSCHAP and MSCHAPv2. It didn't matter whether I enabled any one of them or both. Enabling MPPT did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the method recommended by Andre. Im using EndevourOS and this solved SSTP VPN problems involving my workplace.